# Docker container not finding manage.py using DRF

Tags: django, docker, django-rest-framework

I have been trying to containerise a project of mine that uses `postgresql`. But for some reason it is unable to perform the commands completely, when I check the web container, by following it on docker-desktop I can see that it is performing the `migrations` but at some point it stops and gives me the following error:

```
2023-01-17 19:51:29   Apply all migrations: admin, auth, company, contenttypes, oauth2_provider, product, sessions, social_django, users, warehouse
2023-01-17 19:51:29 Running migrations:
2023-01-17 19:51:29   No migrations to apply.
2023-01-17 19:51:29 sh: manage.py: not found
```

For some reason it does not see manage.py.

When I run `docker-compose run web sh` and when I check if `manage.py` exists in the directory using `ls` in the `CLI` I discover it is there.

What could I be doing wrong here?

The `Dockerfile`:

```
# pull official base image
FROM python:3.9-alpine

# set work directory
WORKDIR /app

# set environment variables
ENV PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE 1
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1

# install psycopg2 dependencies
RUN apk update \
    && apk add postgresql-dev gcc python3-dev musl-dev

# install python dependencies
RUN apk add -u zlib-dev jpeg-dev libffi-dev gcc musl-dev
RUN python3 -m pip install --upgrade pip
COPY requirements.txt /app/requirements.txt
RUN pip install --no-cache-dir -r requirements.txt


# copy project
COPY . .
```

The `docker-compose.yml`:

```
version: '3.9'
services:
  nginx:
    container_name: core_web
    restart: on-failure
    image: nginx:stable
    volumes:
      - ./nginx/nginx.dev.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
      - static_volume:/app/static
    ports:
      - "80:80"
    depends_on:
      - web
  web:
    container_name: web
    build: .
    env_file: .env
    ports:
      - "5000:5000"
    command: >
      sh -c " python manage.py makemigrations && python manage.py migrate &&
           manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:5000"
    volumes:
      - .:/app
      - static_volume:/app/static
    depends_on:
      - db
  db:
    container_name: core_db
    image: postgres:15
    env_file: .env
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_USER=${DB_USER}
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=${DB_PASS}
      - POSTGRES_DB=${DB_NAME}
    volumes:
      - postgres_data:/var/lib/postgresql/data/

volumes:
  static_volume:
  postgres_data:
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed the `web` of my `docker-compose.yml` file:

```
  web:
    tty: true
    container_name: web
    build: .
    restart: always
    env_file: .env
    ports:
      - "5000:5000"
    command: >
      sh -c " python3 /app/manage.py makemigrations && python3 /app/manage.py migrate && python3 /app/manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:5000"
    volumes:
      - .:/app
      - static_volume:/app/static
    depends_on:
      - db
```

Basically, I added `tty: true` and changed command to:

```
sh -c " python3 /app/manage.py makemigrations && python3 /app/manage.py migrate && python3 /app/manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:5000"
```

What I believe was happening:
I did not specify the folder of the location of the `manage.py`, which is what I believe I set in volumes to be `/app`. Thus I had to state in the command its location, feel free to correct me on this.

This made it functional and allowed me to access the backend and its postgres database.